# Visual Studio Code Love2D support extension detecting love.app as a directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, love2d

I have just started with löve because of an internet course I'm on, and I'm using Visual studio code as my editor. The course recommends that I use the "Love2D Support" extension with Visual Studio. It allows me to run the code directly from VS by pressing `Command + L`.
Although when I do it, VS outputs me this error:

`The setting specified in pixelbyte.love2d.path must be an executable file, not a directory. Check your settings.`

The path I have input in the settings is /Users/My_Username/Desktop/love.app

I am 100% sure that it is the correct directory. What is the problem?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Seems like it might be a buggy extensions, I don't know though. When I try to use it, nothing happens, and at the bottom there's a line which says `(⌘L) was pressed. Waiting for the second key of chord...`. I've tried to use a few of those visual studio love2d extensions and had problems with all of them. Usually visual studio extensions aren't that much work, but I don't know, maybe one of them works. I would just try another one, it doesn't look like there's anything special about that one

Comment: @fater Thanks for answering! I got the extension working by switching to my windows computer

Answer (score 1):

The actual executable file in Mac is `/Applications/love.app/Contents/MacOS/love` so put this in your `pixelbyte.love2d.path` command in vscode and you are good to go.